# If (Var == True) { Do this! }

Tags: javascript

I'm brand new to Javascript.

I'm playing around with some code here and can't get my if to work, but my else works.

The problem is with (solved == true), it's not working. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
 <script>
        solved = true
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function solvedTrue(){
            var solved = true
            console.log("Solved is now " + solved)
    }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function solvedFalse(){
            var solved = false
            console.log("Solved is now " + solved)
    }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            function checkStatus(){
            console.log("Currently it's " + solved)
    }
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            function tester(){
                if (solved = true) {
                alert('it worked') }
                else {
                    alert('Did not work')
</script>

    <button onclick="tester()">If/Else Test</button>
    <button onclick="solvedTrue()">True</button>
    <button onclick="solvedFalse()">False</button>
    <button onclick="checkStatus()">What's the Status?</button>
```

Comment: You're declaring `solved` inside a function, so it's scoped to that function and inaccessible elsewhere.  Also your  `if` statement sets the variable to true, instead of testing it; use `==` or `===` instead of `=`.   (Lastly -- this won't break anything, but it's unnecessary to use separate `<script>` tags for each function; you can put all that stuff in a single script block.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a global variable `solved` and you use a local variable in the function where the global variable does not change the value.

You need just the global variable.

```
var solved = true; // use var for declaration a variable

function solvedTrue(){
    solved = true; // no var, because you want to take the global var
    console.log("Solved is now " + solved)
}
```

Then you need to check the variable without an assignment.

```
if (solved === true) {
```

or shorter use the value directly with a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value

```
if (solved) {
```

```js
function solvedTrue() {
    solved = true;
    console.log("Solved is now " + solved);
}

function solvedFalse() {
    solved = false;
    console.log("Solved is now " + solved);
}

function checkStatus() {
    console.log("Currently it's " + solved);
}

function tester() {
    if (solved) {
        alert('it worked');
    } else {
        alert('Did not work');
    }
}

var solved = true;
```

```html
<button onclick="tester()">If/Else Test</button>
<button onclick="solvedTrue()">True</button>
<button onclick="solvedFalse()">False</button>
<button onclick="checkStatus()">What's the Status?</button>
```

Comment: Great answer. Why the triple `=`. Long time since I wrote Javascript, can't remember using triple `=`

Comment: @niCkcAMel Triple `=` also checks for type equality, you can see the difference in your javascript console, try running `true == 1` then `true === 1`

Comment: @UncleDave Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have solved = true but you should change it for solved == true. And like someone said it is inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing `var` in you upper definition of `solved = true`. Also as other have mentioned, test a condition using double equals `solved == true`
Or triple `=`, as some has suggested...

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring solved inside a function, so it's scoped to that function and inaccessible elsewhere. Also your if statement sets the variable to true, instead of testing it; use `==` or `===` instead of `=`.

(Lastly -- this won't break anything, but it's unnecessary to use separate  tags for each function; you can put all that stuff in a single script block.)

Here's a version of your code with those issues corrected:

```js
var solved = true // var here makes it global.  This is not strictly necessary, but it's good practice.

function solvedTrue() {
  solved = true   // don't use "var" here; it would create a separate variable scoped to this function
  console.log("Solved is now " + solved)
}

function solvedFalse() {
  solved = false
  console.log("Solved is now " + solved)
}

function checkStatus() {
  console.log("Currently it's " + solved)
}

function tester() {
  if (solved) { // or use   if (solved === true).   solved=true sets the value instead of testing it.
    alert('true')
  } else {
    alert('false')
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="tester()">If/Else Test</button>
<button onclick="solvedTrue()">True</button>
<button onclick="solvedFalse()">False</button>
<button onclick="checkStatus()">What's the Status?</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create multiple vars named `solved`. For instance in this function

```
function solvedTrue(){
        var solved = true
        console.log("Solved is now " + solved)
}
```

The var `solved` will only be visible inside the function `solvedTrue()`. So it is NOT the same var you created at the top with

```
solved = true;
```

You need to end lines of code with a semicolon which you failed to do throughout your code.

Not related to your problem but you need to know that it isn't necessary to repeatedly use the `<script>` tag.  Here's a revised version of your script.

```
<script>
var solved = true; //this will be visible to all functions

function solvedTrue() {
    solved = true;
    console.log("Solved is now " + solved);
}


function solvedFalse() {
    solved = false;
    console.log("Solved is now " + solved);
}

function checkStatus() {
    console.log("Currently it's " + solved);
}

function tester() {
    if (solved === true) //use equality not assignment
    {
        alert('it worked');
    } 
    else
    {
        alert('Did not work');
    }
}
</script>
```